# Prove that f is always strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose a function $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) > 0$ for all numbers $x$ except for a single number $d$. How do I prove that $f$ is always increasing? I've seen similar proofs to this but I'm trying to figure out why the single number $d$ information was given and how do I go about using that in my proof?

Comment: $f$ must be continuous, so $d$ can't cause too many problems.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $f' > 0$ everywhere except $x = d$, then what can you determine about $f'(d)$?

Comment: I'm having trouble with this, because if for example $f'(x) = \sin x + 1$ there are multiple points where $f'(x) = 0$ but $x - \cos x$ is still an increasing function. Think about why. At the single point $f(d) = 0$ you get a point of inflection where either side of it the function is still clearly increasing.

Comment: @AmaanM I'm guessing d is an inflection point? such that f'(x)=0 at d? I'm quite lost at this point to be honest I'm not sure how to write a formal proof on this

Comment: Here's a hint: If $f'(d)$ were negative, then there would have to be some neighborhood around $d$ such that $f' < 0$ in that neighborhood (why? - think about differentiability of $f$ and what that tells you about continuity of $f'$). If you can demonstrate that, then you know that $f'(d) \ge 0$ everywhere, which further implies that $f$ is an increasing function. Theorems that might help complete the logic are the the [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and the [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

The key theorem is that when $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f'>0$ for $(a,b)$, then we have $f(b)>f(a).$ Also note we can replace $>$ with $\geq$ in both the hypothesis and conclusion.
Assume without loss that $d=0$ and $f(0)=0$. Let $s=f'(0).$

First we show that $s<0$ cannot be. For if it were, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ on $(-\delta,0),$ while $f(x)<0$ on $(0,\delta).$ In particular, $f(-\delta/2)>0$ and $f(\delta/2)<0.$ But this contradicts the strict form of the theorem applied to $[-\delta/2,0].$

The only choice left is $s=0$. We want to show that $f(\alpha)<f(\beta)$ follows from $\alpha<\beta.$ The only hard case is when $\alpha<0<\beta.$ By applying the $\geq$ version of the theorem to $[\alpha,\beta]$, we obtain $f(\beta)\geq f(\alpha).$ So all that remains is to eliminate the chance that $f(\beta)=f(\alpha).$

Consider the intervals $[\alpha,0]$ and $[0,\beta].$ Apply the strict version of the theorem to each. From this we get $f(\alpha)<0<f(\beta).$

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need that $f$ is differentiable at the point $d$, just that it's continuous.

The function is strictly increasing over the interval $(-\infty,d)$ and over $(d,\infty)$ by the mean value theorem.

It is also strictly increasing over the closed intervals $(-\infty,d]$ and $[d,\infty)$, by continuity.

Indeed, you can easily prove that $\lim_{x\to d^-}f(x)=\sup\{f(x):x<d\}$ holds for every function that's (weakly) increasing over an interval $(a,d]$ and continuity tells you that $\sup\{f(x):x<d\}=f(d)$. Take $a<d$ and $a'$ such that $a<a'<d$; then $f(a)<f(a')\le f(d)$ (by definition of supremum), so $f(a)<f(d)$. Similarly for $[d,\infty)$.

So the only problem is to prove that, if $a<d$ and $b>d$, it holds that $f(a)<f(b)$. But this is obvious, now, because
$$
f(a)<f(d)<f(b)
$$

Note that the same argument shows that a continuous function which is differentiable with positive derivative over an interval, except over a set of points without an accumulation point, is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

The critical point is the growth of $f$ at $d$. If $a<d<b$, we have, by Lagrange's Theorem:

$$ f(d)-f(a)=f'(c)(d-a)>0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad f(b)-f(d)=f'(c')(b-d)>0, $$

where $a<c<d<c'<b$. So $f(a)<f(d)<f(b)$, i.e. $f$ is strictly increasing.

**Note** that $f'(d)=0$ by Darboux Theorem [$f'$ has the intermediate value property].