# A function is strictly increasing despite its derivative being somewhere zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and \begin{align*}
g: \mathbb{R} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R},&\
g(x) = x+\cos x - a.
\end{align*}

I want to prove that $g$ is strictly increasing. But the derivative is not everywhere zero. I tried the intermediate theorem, and  also tried proving that $x<y\implies g(x)<g(y),$ but no luck.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I think the asker's concern is that the derivative isn't positive everywhere, but becomes zero at isolated points.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489495/non-negative-derivative-not-being-zero-function-on-all-subintervals-implies-st, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143209/prove-that-f-is-always-strictly-increasing, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = x^3$, which is strictly increasing everywhere, despite the presence of the *isolated point* $~x=0. ~$ At this isolated point, $~f'(x) = 0.$